# Gmail API php listUserMesages() null

Tags: php, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-php-client

I am doing a very basic test of Gmail API using PHP.  I am using the code supplied by Google (after a successful authorization via OAuth followed by a successful -- code 200 -- test run on the API workbench. My error is:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function listUsersMessages() on null

The line that fails:

```
$messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($userId, $opt_param);
```

The full Code:

```
    $userId = 'my gmail id';
    $service = 'my api client id, for example,12356686375';
    $messages = listMessages($service,$userId);
/**
 * Get list of Messages in user's mailbox.
 *
 * @param  Google_Service_Gmail $service Authorized Gmail API instance.
 * @param  string $userId User's email address. The special value 'me'
 * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
 * @return array Array of Messages.
 */
function listMessages($service, $userId) {
  $pageToken = NULL;
  $messages = array();
  $opt_param = array();
  do {
    try {
      if ($pageToken) {
        $opt_param['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
      }
      $messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($userId, $opt_param);
      if ($messagesResponse->getMessages()) {
        $messages = array_merge($messages, $messagesResponse->getMessages());
        $pageToken = $messagesResponse->getNextPageToken();
      }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
  } while ($pageToken);

  foreach ($messages as $message) {
    print 'Message with ID: ' . $message->getId() . '<br/>';
  }

  return $messages;
        }
```

Comment: I think the problem is the `$service` variable. That variable should have the Gmail service initialized and not the client id.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Morfinismo, `$service` variable should have the Gmail service initialized and not the client id.

It should be:

```
// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
```

You may follow this [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php).